# C - fread() to buffer index

Tags: c, buffer, fread

This is in C

I was wondering if it was possible to fread() to a certain index of a buffer.

For example:

fread(buffer[10],1,5,file)

buffer[10] =  something
buffer[11] = something
...
...
buffer[14] = something

Is this possible somehow?  This would need to be done without any additional buffers. (tight memory constraints)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
fread(buffer+10, 1, 5, file);
```

Should do it. I trust you made sure the count is within the buffer limits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a pointer to the place you want to store the data. There are two ways to do this (but really it's just the same way but with different syntax).

1. Use of the address-of operator `&`: `&buffer[10]`
2. To use pointer arithmetic: `buffer + 10`

Answer (score 0):

first argument of fread is pointer. In that case you can do this: fread(buffer+10, 1, 5, file) and you will get the desired behaviour. That is because buffer+i is pointer to i-th cell of array "buffer".